# Modifying a pytorch tensor and then getting the gradient lets the gradient not work

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

I am a beginner in pytorch and I face the following issue:

When I get the gradient of the below tensor (note that I use some variable x in some way as you can see below), I get the gradient:

```
import torch
myTensor = torch.randn(2, 2,requires_grad=True)
with torch.enable_grad():
    x=myTensor.sum() *10
x.backward()
print(myTensor.grad)
```

Now, if I try to modify an element of `myTensor`, I get the error of `leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior`. See this code:

```
import torch
myTensor = torch.randn(2, 2,requires_grad=True)
myTensor[0,0]*=5
with torch.enable_grad():
    x=myTensor.sum() *10
x.backward()
print(myTensor.grad)
```

What is wrong with my latter code? And how do I correct it?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much. I just added a comment indicating that your answer worked beautifully. Thanks again! On another related note, could you please take a look into this related one that I recently posted and haven't gotten any replies to yet?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507346/gradient-is-none-in-pytorch-when-it-shouldny

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that this line represents an *in-place* operation:

```
myTensor[0,0]*=5
```

And *PyTorch* or more precisely *autograd* is not very good in handling *in-place* operations, especially on those tensors with the `requires_grad` flag set to `True`.

You can also take a look here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd

Generally you should avoid *in-place* operations where it is possible, in some cases it can work, but you should always avoid *in-place* operations on tensors where you set `requires_grad` to `True`.

Unfortunately there are not many pytorch functions to help out on this problem. So you would have to use a helper tensor to avoid the `in-place` operation in this case:

**Code:**

```py
import torch

myTensor = torch.randn(2, 2,requires_grad=True)
helper_tensor = torch.ones(2, 2)
helper_tensor[0, 0] = 5
new_myTensor = myTensor * helper_tensor # new tensor, out-of-place operation
with torch.enable_grad():
    x=new_myTensor.sum() *10 # of course you need to use the new tensor
x.backward()                 # for further calculation and backward
print(myTensor.grad)
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([[50., 10.],
        [10., 10.]])
```

Unfortunately this is not very nice and I would appreciate if there would be a better or nicer solution out there. 
But for all I know in the current version *(0.4.1)* you will have to got with this workaround for tensors with gradient resp. `requires_grad=True`.

Hopefully for future versions there will be a better solution.

---

Btw. if you activate the gradient later you can see that it works just fine:

```
import torch
myTensor = torch.randn(2, 2,requires_grad=False) # no gradient so far
myTensor[0,0]*=5                                 # in-place op not included in gradient
myTensor.requires_grad = True                    # activate gradient here
with torch.enable_grad():
    x=myTensor.sum() *10
x.backward()                                     # no problem here
print(myTensor.grad)
```

But of course this will yield to a different result:

```
tensor([[10., 10.],
        [10., 10.]])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you very much for the very clear and correct answer!

Comment: Done, voted and accepted it, with absolute appreciation :-). And yes, would appreciate you looking at the other one. Thanks a lot!